# Silverlight in WPF WebBrowser control under x64

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls, browser

is there a way to run SilverLight in WPF WebBrowser control in x64 mode? (Same problem is with Flash).

Compiling application in x86 mode only is not a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: no.

Currently the Silverlight plugin is 32 bit only and therefore can only run in a 32 bit process.

It would seem that the upcoming Silverlight 5 plugin will have a 64bit version.